# Error converting data type varchar to int

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net

This is my stored procedure code

```
ALTER procedure [Proc_Add_User]
    (@UserId varchar(20), 
     @UserName varchar(100),
     @Page_Name varchar(20), 
     @AccessIndicator int, 
     @CreatedBy varchar(50), 
     @returnStatus varchar(50) output)
as
   DECLARE @intErrorCode INT
DECLARE @Page_Indicator INT
begin
BEGIN TRAN
Set @Page_Indicator = (select Page_Indicator from Pages where Page_Name=@Page_Name);
if (select count(*) from Users where UserId=@UserId and UserName=@UserName) > 0 begin               
    if (select count(*) from User_Credentials where Page_Indicator=@Page_Indicator and 
    UserId=@UserId  ) > 0 
    set @returnStatus='User already has access'             
    else 
    insert into User_Credentials(UserId,Page_Indicator,Access_Indicator,CreatedBy) 
        values (@UserId,@Page_Indicator,@AccessIndicator,@CreatedBy)
    SELECT @intErrorCode = @@ERROR
    IF (@intErrorCode <> 0) GOTO PROBLEM            
end
else begin  
    insert into Users(UserId,UserName,CreatedBy) 
    values(@UserId,@UserName,@CreatedBy)
    SELECT @intErrorCode = @@ERROR
    IF (@intErrorCode <> 0) GOTO PROBLEM
    insert into User_Credentials(UserId,Page_Indicator,Access_Indicator,CreatedBy) 
        values (@UserId,@Page_Indicator,@AccessIndicator,@CreatedBy)
    SELECT @intErrorCode = @@ERROR
    IF (@intErrorCode <> 0) GOTO PROBLEM    
end
COMMIT TRAN
if(@returnStatus is null)
    set @returnStatus='Success';
PROBLEM:
IF (@intErrorCode <> 0) BEGIN
set @returnStatus= 'Unexpected error occurred!'
ROLLBACK TRAN
end
end
```

And I am calling this from the code pasted below:

```
Con.Open();
cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.Connection = Con;

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "Proc_Add_User";

cmd.Parameters.Clear();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userLanId;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userName;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Page_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = pageName;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@AccessIndicator", SqlDbType.Int).Value = accessIndicator;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@CreatedBy", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = createdBy;

OleDbParameter output = new OleDbParameter("@returnStatus", SqlDbType.VarChar);
output.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add(output); 

int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I am getting the error mentioned at the `ExecuteNonQuery` statement. What's confusing to me is I am able to execute the stored procedure in SSMS but not from my application (front-end). I provided the same values too yet it fails from my app.

I double checked to make sure the order of parameters passed match and are of same data type but still it throws this error. I can paste my stored proc code here if wanted so let me know..Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

OOPS! I just realized that all the inserts are all happening and getting committed fine in the database. It's just this error is getting caught inside catch block in my app. Any ideas?

I can not ignore it because based on the return value of ExecuteNonQuery(), I have some statements and also it's not going through the code present after ExecuteNonQuery().

Comment: Tough to help if your code says something other than `my code here`.

Comment: What datatype is `accessIndicator` in code? Might be attempting to convert a `string` to an `int` and failing.

Comment: Is really UserID a VARCHAR?

Comment: UserId is defined as varchar(20) and accessIndicator as int in their respective tables

Comment: @Downvoters please explain irrespective how silly my ques is!

Comment: Okay.  I flagged my answer for deletion.  Sorry about that OP and everyone else!

Comment: It's getting caught by the catch block in your app, but the @returnStatus is showing "Success"? I'd place a break point at `ExecuteNonQuery` and check the parameters going in.

Comment: I inserted a break point and see 6 parameters going in which is fine..I see propoerty ChangeId has a value of 7, not sure what it is! @returnStatus does not have a value at all because of exception being caught!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely because you are using `SqlDbType` with `OleDbParameters`:

```
OleDbParameter output = new OleDbParameter("@returnStatus", SqlDbType.VarChar);
```

This causes .NET to use the `OleDbParameter(String, Object)` constructor, setting the value of the parameter to `SqlDbType.VarChar` which it assumes is an `int`.

You should use this instead:

```
OleDbParameter output = new OleDbParameter("@returnStatus", OleDbType.VarChar);
```

And change your calls to `cmd.Parameters.Add` to use `OleDbType` as well.

Alternatively, you could use `System.Data.SqlClient` instead of OleDb

Comment: Woohoo! It started working after making this tweak! Thanks again!